# Parsing a nested JSON in ngFor when the keys are unknown

Tags: javascript, json, angular

```
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="form-control btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="serverName"  >
      <option  data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery'></i>" *ngFor="let instance of instances" [ngValue]="instance.insturl">{{instance.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

This is my HTML selector

Earlier it was working when I maintained a flat hierarchy!

```
instances= [ {instanceurl: 'http://instances-url',
      name: 'instance-name', versionURL: '2017.6'},
    {instanceurl: 'http://instances-url',
      name: 'machine name', versionURL: '2017.5'
    }];
```

But now i made it nested because i want to pass the object to the backend not a value.

```
    instances= [ {name:
        {'instance-name(this is dynamic)':{
                  instanceurl: 'http://instances-url',
               , versionURL: '2017.6'}}},
{name:
    {'machine name(this is dynamic)':{
              instanceurl: 'http://instances-url',
           , versionURL: '2017.5'}}}
            ];
```

Now this doesn't work! How to get around ngFor and still get the same values as i used to get?
I know that when i do ngFor let instance of instances it give me the array object. So i can do instance.name but it will return an object of keys i don't know because it's dynamic. How to make my way through this nested json?

Comment: Your JSON structure seems to have some problems. I'd start with that first!

"name" isn't a name in your new object, it's an object with some other properties? And then inside that, you have 'instance-name(this is dynamic)' as the name of the other object...

Really it's best NOT to use dynamic names, and to have a fairly regular or static JSON structure.

I cannot really think of any good reasons why you would need such a dynamic structure. And the methods of dealing with it are quite complex! (you'd have to iterate through the array, store a list of different names then check them all)

Comment: @NightCabbage Then how can i structure it? the whole idea is to display the machine name in the drop down! in the flat hierarchy i had name: machine name it was simple now it's not :(

Answer (score 1):

You should process your data:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'myfilter'})
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(instances) {
    return instances.map(function(a){
        var name = Object.keys(a.name)[0];
        return {name, insturl: a.name[name].instanceurl};
    });
  }
}

<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="form-control btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="serverName"  >
      <option  data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery'></i>" *ngFor="let instance of instances | myfilter" [ngValue]="instance.insturl">{{instance.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need it as a drop down! I'm thinking of using pipes!

Comment: But how will I get this in ngFor so that i can display machine names as a select option?

Comment: @RaghavendraSS, now it is presented as `Pipe`.

Comment: I have to write a separate component.ts for this right? then add this pipeclass? Also there will be multiple values so hard coded [0] won't work ! Should we go for jquery foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, also you should add it into `declarations` array of your module.

Comment: It will still work, because you just added another item, not changed object's structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you may do is that you could repeat all possible entries that you can find in your Nested JSON. For safety you can use a `safe navigation operator ?` to reflect in the DOM only if it exists in the model. For example you could do something like:

`{{instance?.name}}
 {{instance?.machineName}}`

This may seem like a workaround this would work efficiently.

Comment: the machine name changes dynamically i don't know after name key what's the value of the next key : values inside it.

Comment: I think there is no other go but to structure your model in a organized manner so as to Observe and Subscribe to data that is only recommended by you. If you do not know what data you receive, then you are not in control of your data.

Answer (score 0):

For this json data :

```
instances= [ 
    {
        name:
        {
            'instance-name(this is dynamic)':
            {
                instanceurl: 'http://instances-url',
                versionURL: '2017.6'
            }
        }
    },
];
```

You can use `Object.keys` :

```
<option  
    data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery'></i>" 
    *ngFor="let instance of instances" 
    [ngValue]="instance['name'][Object.keys(instance['name'])[0]].instanceurl">
    {{instance.name}}
</option>
```

Comment: i can't use [0] because if there are mulitple JSON objects in the array it will retrieve only the first one!

Comment: it's just for fetching key name nothing else , it will work.